# What is the best way to show a lot (more then 40) of PDF files in iPhone App

Tags: ios, xcode, pdf

Im making a App that will show the user a list of people, when the user selects a person I want to show a PDF file that has more information about this person.

I know I need to use the UIWebView but Im not sure if that is the best way for the amount of people I have.

Comment: Loading the PDFs on the fly in a navigation controller based view sounds like the way to go. Or is there a performance issue with your PDFs when doing that?

Comment: UIWebView is great for files under 150 MB

Comment: the PDF files are under 100MB

Comment: QLPreviewController is also a great way to do stuff !

Comment: A few questions: 1) Why do you want to display a PDF instead of just a view? 2) Are the PDFs going to be pre-made or are you looking to generate each one on the fly as the user selects the person? 3) Are you planning on storing the PDFs for any reason?

Comment: I just assumed that a PDF file was the best choice, the PDF files will be pre made with the person's details( Name, contact number, website, picture, and apx 25 words describing what they do).

If there is a better way to display that information please let me know, I'm very new to Xcode so there might be something amazing that I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

You could load them into a WebView like this

```
NSString *pdfPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pdfName" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:pdfPath];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
```

or really drawing them via CGPDFDocument.

Read this quite short Tutorial http://www.cocoanetics.com/2010/06/rendering-pdf-is-easier-than-you-thought/

Comment: You can do zoom in the webView if you draw the pdf files then you would have to use an catiledlayer

Comment: Yes! Was meant for the comment above ! don't know how it got posted here !

Comment: Using the code above, how would I be able to have a lot of PDF files for different web views ? (e.g., person A is a.pdf and person B is b.pdf)

Comment: Just load the pdf you want to show in the webview if you want to show multiple pdfs at the same time (what i don't know if it is a great experience on iOS devices) just dynamically instantiate more webView's

Answer (score 0):

Use UITableView to show your list of people.  When a person is selected, push a new view controller to show the details (i.e. your PDF).  So you'll have a basic Navigation based app.  On iPad, this would work nicely with a SplitViewController.

Comment: I would love to use that but at the moment this App will only be for the iPhone. Thank you I will remember that for next time.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the open source code for PDFReader which is available on [github](https://github.com/vfr/Reader)